# Converting .png to .ico leaves black border

Tags: export, file-conversion, favicon

I'm trying to convert a .png (with transparant bg) to a .ico file to use as a favicon. Whenever I put it in any converter online (tried multiple) it leaves a black border around the object, which I don't want.

- Does this have anything to do with the transparency? If so, what color bg should I use since a lot of browsers have different color UI?
- Could I export an .ico from Sketch/Illustrator/Photoshop as well?

Comment: There's an ico plugin for Photoshop here: http://www.telegraphics.com.au/sw/product/ICOFormat - I just tested it on Photoshop CC 2017.

Comment: Author of RealFaviconGenerator speaking: ICO does support transparency. Converting a transparent PNG to ICO should work just fine. Please give a try to RealFaviconGenerator. If the generated ICO is still wrong, please email me the PNG so I can review it.

Answer (score 4):

Without access to the file in question it will be hard for anyone to say for certain what your issue is...

As an alternative you could always use the free and open source program GIMP (GNU Image Manipulation Program). See here: [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org)

Open your .png file in GIMP by choosing File > Open and then double-clicking on it:

[image: Open png file in GIMP]

And then export your .png as an .ico file simply by changing the file extension from png to ico then pressing enter twice:

[image: Export png as ico]

Comment: Two people found this answer useful but somebody here thinks it's so bad that it ought to just be deleted... Diversity LOL. To whoever voted to delete: why not leave a comment and explain your reasoning?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a limitation of the graphics software you're using.

Is there any reason you need an .ico file? You can use a PNG for your favicon. It's supported by all modern browsers.